# Probability that the fish that set off metal detector is the one true fish

Tags: probability, machine-learning, bayes-theorem

I have exams in Machine Learning coming up and I need help answering this question.

> There are a million identical fish in a lake, one of which has
>   swallowed the One True Ring. You must get it back! After months of
>   effort, you catch another random fish and pass your metal detector
>   over it, and the detector beeps! It is the best metal detector money
>   can buy, and has a very low error rate: it fails to beep when near the
>   ring only one in a billion times, and it beeps incorrectly only one in
>   ten thousand times. What is the probability that, at long last, you’ve
>   found your precious ring?

This is my answer I worked out using Bayes rule:

[image]

Is this the right way to work out this type of question and is that somewhat the correct answer?

Comment: What is the probability that if your professor finds this question posted on a site, asking for help, that you'll not be expelled?

Comment: The probability is pretty low actually because it's not homework, it's a previous exam question.

Comment: Ah, then carry on :)

Comment: you mean the probability is pretty high, not pretty low. :)

Comment: Are you sure? Genuine question, because I'm a bit confused now. If the probability of my professor finding this question and getting expelled was high then I should take it down, but because it's **not** homework then the probability of this happening is low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have mixed up a few of your conditional probabilities. If the detector *fails* to beep over the ring only one in a billion times, then it *does* beep the rest of the billion times. Similarly, if it beeps over he wrong fish one in ten thousand times, then it doesn't beep on the rest of those ten thousand wrong fish. So you should have
\begin{align}
P(B|\tilde{A}) &= \frac{1}{10000}\\
P(\tilde{B}|\tilde{A}) &= \frac{9999}{10000}\\
P(\tilde{B}|A) &= \frac{1}{1000000000}\\
P(B|A) &= \frac{999999999}{1000000000}
\end{align}
which is different from what you do have. Using these values gives
\begin{align}
P(B) & =\frac{999999999}{1000000000}\frac{1}{1000000}
+\frac{1}{10000}\frac{999999}{1000000} \\
& =\frac{999999999}{1,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000}
+\frac{999999}{10,\!000,\!000,\!000} \\
& = \frac{100,\!999,\!899,\!999}{1,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
P(A|B) & = \frac{\frac{999999999}{1000000000}\frac{1}{1000000}}
{\frac{100999899999}{1000000000000000}} \\
& = \frac{999,\!999,\!999}{1,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000}
\frac{1,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000,\!000}{100,\!999,\!899,\!999} \\
& = \frac{999,\!999,\!999}{100,\!999,\!899,\!999}\approx 0.0099
\end{align}
Or slightly less than $1$%. To check, we can make a quick estimate of the answer. There are almost one million fish that *don't* have the ring. The detector gives a false positive one in ten thousand times. So, if you were to test every fish in the lake, you would get approximately $100$ beeps. Of all the fish that trigger beeps, only one has the ring, which means that the detector would only be right about once in every hundred beeps, or $1$% of the time.

In regards to the other part of your question, yes, your methods were correct. It was just your starting values that were wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Surely the probability of the detector beeping if you have found the fish is 999999999/1000000000 not 9999/10000
Whereas the probability of the detector not beeping when the fish is not found is 9999/10000 not 999999999/1000000000?

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. I think my issue here is that this question is worth 25% of my final grade for this module (4th Year Computer Science) and it just seems too simple of an answer for a question with such a huge weight attached to it.

Comment: Ah ok interesting. Maybe the point is to see that you can think logically and keep track of all the different variables and large numbers that are cropping up, also the Bayes rule is so powerful the main thing that you get marks for is to remember its statement and know how to apply it. Just remember for the exam to let yourself think slowly and to write every step down really clearly and take your time as its so easy to make a little mistake in probability, then you might be surprised at how short the exam is but you have convinced yourself that way you are doing is right. Good luck with it:)

Comment: By the way I think your method is absolutely correct. Just did it myself with those adjustments to the figures and I got (999 999 999)/(100 000 899 999) $\simeq$ 0.01.. though maybe check that against someone else I may have made a mistake

Answer (score 1):

You have $2$ cases in which the detector will beep:

$1:$ You have found the fish with the ring and the detector beeps. Probability:

$$\frac{1}{10^6} \cdot (1-\frac{1}{10^9}) = 9.99999999 \cdot 10^{-7}$$

$2:$ You have not found the fish with the ring but the detector beeps anyway. Probability:

$$\frac{10^6 -1}{10^6} \cdot \frac{1}{10^4} = 0.0000999999$$

To get the probability that you catched the correct fish under the condition that your detector beeped is then

$$\frac{\frac{1}{10^6} \cdot (1-\frac{1}{10^9})}{\frac{1}{10^6} \cdot (1-\frac{1}{10^9})+\frac{10^6 -1}{10^6} \cdot \frac{1}{10^4}}= \frac{1001001}{101101001} \approx 0.9901 \%,$$ so slightly less than $1\%$.